# Remove extra space from radialBar Apexcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, apexcharts

I am new to apexcharts and cannot figure out how to remove the extra space in this radialBar chart.

I want to have the same type of donut chart which I have created but without having extra spaces around it.

my Code having Javascript and HTML:

as you can see in the "chart:" there is height set but still, I am getting the whitespace

```js
var options = {
 chart: {
   
    height:140,
    width:100,
    
   type: 'radialBar',
    offsetY: 0,
   toolbar: {
  show: false
   }
 },
 plotOptions: {
   radialBar: {
  size:50,
   hollow: {
    margin: 0,
    size: '65%',
    background: '#fff',
  },
  track: {
    background: '#F5F5FF',
    strokeWidth: '75%',
    margin: 0, // margin is in pixels
    
  },
  dataLabels: {
    showOn: 'always',
    name: {
   offsetY: 0,
   show: false,
   color: '#003366',
   fontSize: '17px'
    },
    value: {
   formatter: function(val) {
     return parseInt(val);
   },
   color: '#003366',
   fontSize: '18px',
   show: true,
   offsetY: 10,
    }
  }
   }
 },
 fill: {
   colors:['#57CAF0']
 },
 series: [75],
 stroke: {
   lineCap: 'round'
 },
 

  }

  var chart = new ApexCharts(
 document.querySelector("#chart"),
 options
  );

  chart.render();
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
```

my code link

```
https://codepen.io/wasifhafeez/pen/JjPyGNa?editors=1010
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in ApexCharts.
I have just pushed a [commit](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/commit/b0c9886bbee38044c3d3ba9ec709d3381b26fb55) which removes unnecessary spacing for radialBar charts.